# When do I need the maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: maven

I understand that the maven-compiler plugin is used to compile the code. Some of my project does not have that plugin in the pom file? When is it required?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am trying to answer my own question based on what I learned since posted this question. If this answer is correct or incorrect please comment. Thanks.

If this plugin is not defined, the Maven Super POM contains all [the default plugins](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) you will be using. It works fine for small and non-serious projects. However, the best practice is **to define these plugins in a company-wise POM** and so that when you upgrade maven, you would not end up using a different version of plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Goals Overview Section in [Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)

> The Compiler Plugin has two goals. Both are already bound to their proper phases within the Maven Lifecycle and are therefore, automatically executed during their respective phases.

You only have to add it if you want to change the default parameters

Comment: that still doesn't answers the question. every maven plugin has goal/goals that are attached to a particular lifecycle phase of maven. your interpretation of the context is wrong. Devs love ZenUML answer is the one that totally makes sense.